# canvas getImageData returns too many pixels

Tags: javascript, canvas, getimagedata

I'm creating a mobile webapp game that lets the user swipe over the screen to clear it.
I am trying to write a smart function that detects when nearly the whole canvas is transparent.

I have an interval that calls the function below each second, to do the check.
The way it is supposed to work is that I take a sector of the canvas that is 20px wide, and as tall as the canvas is.

This function should run quite smooth, but for some reason, the getImageData function, returns to many pixels. My sector is always 20px wide and has the same height, so it should return the same amount of pixels each time. Of course, since getImageData returns a higher and higher number, my loop gets slower and slower.

Does anyone know what causes this? have I misunderstood the getImageData function in the way it works?

```
isCanvasTransparent: function (fromX, toX, currentIteration) {

        if(currentIteration < this.clearedIterations) { // If a sector is already clear, we dont need to check it again
            this.isCanvasTransparent(fromX + 20, toX + 20, currentIteration + 1);
            return;
        } else {
            var data = this.context.getImageData(fromX, 0, toX, parseInt(this.canvas.style.width)).data;
            var counter = 0;
            var i = 0;

            // For some reason, the length increases, but the diff between fromX and toX is always 20
            console.log(data.length); 

            for(i=0;i<(data.length);i+=4) { 
                if(data[i+3]!==0){
                    counter++;
                    // I stop iterating, since there are too many non transparent pixels
                    if(counter > 10) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // I accept that 10 pixels in each sector is not transparent
            if((counter < 10) && !this.alerted) {
                this.clearedIterations++; // Here we increase clearedIterations, since this sector is clear

                // There are no more iterations, so we are done
                if(currentIteration === this.maxIterations) {
                     // this is the interval that calls isCanvasTransparent(0, 20, 0)
                     // in the first place. The interval is called each second. But as soon the whole view
                     // is transparent, we clear it, so that isCanvasTransparent is no longer called
                    clearInterval(this.checkCanvasTimeout);
                    this.alerted = true;
                    TouchHelpers.removeTouchEvents();
                    this.levelCompleted();
                    return;
                } else {
                    // this sector is clear, but we need to check the next one, since we are not at the end
                    this.isCanvasTransparent(fromX + 20, toX + 20, currentIteration + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not certain without seeing how you set fromX/toX, but it looks like you're not giving getImageData the proper parameters.

`context.getImageData` has these parameters:

- x: starting x coordinate to extract,
- y: starting y coordinate to extract,
- width: extract a block this many pixels wide,
- height: extract a block this many pixels high

**[ Addition: based on additional info  ]**

If you want equal sized chunks of pixel data, your first call is

```
var data=getImageData(0,0, 20, canvas.height).data;
```

And your second call would be:

```
// Note: the width arguement remains at 20, not increase to 40

var data=getImageData(20,0, 20, canvas.height).data;
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I tried explaining this in the clearinterval code you see there. But anyways the way I initially call the function is with these parameter (0,0, 20, <height of the canvas>). Then it recursively moves 20 pixels to the right the next time. So second time (20, 0, 40, <height of the canvas>) is called.

Comment: There's the problem...Your second call s/b (20,0,20,canvas.height) -- the 3rd width argument should remain at 20, not increase to 40.  Cheers!

Comment: Ahhh... you're absolutely right! Now my function works really smoothly. I can't thank you enough for this! Really appreciate it! :)